# Error in my trigger statement

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

please help me find the error on my trigger statement.

```
CREATE TRIGGER textmain_insert BEFORE INSERT ON textmain
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.text_create_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.text_create_datetime = NOW();
    END IF
    IF NEW.text_update_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.text_update_datetime = NOW();
    END IF
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the `delimiter`
- terminate after each `end if`

try,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER textmain_insert BEFORE INSERT ON textmain
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.text_create_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.text_create_datetime = NOW();
    END IF;
    IF NEW.text_update_datetime = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
        SET NEW.text_update_datetime = NOW();
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```